# check the text of the buttons in the array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have 5 buttons and they are in an array. While text of the buttons unequal to `cevapLabel.Text`, I want to hide them randomize. how to check all buttons text?

like this; 
`while allButtonsText != cevapLabel.Text {}`

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func eliminateChoiceClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let num = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
    let buttons:[UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]
    while  buttons != cevapLabel.text {

        buttons[num].isHidden = !buttons[num].isHidden
    }

}
```

in this code its show this error: " Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[UIButton]' and 'String?' "

---**EDITED**---

I had to make a few changes in my project.

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func eliminateChoiceClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    var buttons: [UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]

    for _ in 1...3 {

        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))
        let button = buttons.remove(at: randomNumber)
        button.isHidden = true
    }

    for button in buttons {
        button.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

I tried like this:

```
@IBAction func eliminateChoiceClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    var buttons: [UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]
    for x in buttons {
        if x.titleLabel?.text != cevapLabel.text {

            for _ in 1...3 {

                let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))
                let button = buttons.remove(at: randomNumber)
                button.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        else {
            for button in buttons {
                button.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i got that error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Comment: buttons.count-1 instead of buttons.count in your random is probably causing your crash because the array's size exceeds the last index by 1

Comment: PS: This edit represents a new question which already has numerous answers on SO. Please consider reaccepting my answer as it did answer the original question.

Comment: its show : Thread 1: Fatal error: Negative value is not representable

Comment: Calling arc4random_uniform() will generate a random value ranging from 0 to 1 less than the parameter. For example, calling arc4random_uniform(5) will generate values from 0 to 4. Try printing the value of buttons.count before calling arc4random_uniform() to find out why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because you're comparing an array of UIButtons with a String.

You can fix your issue by creating a func returning a Bool and calling it in your while statement like so:

```
@IBAction func eliminateChoiceClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let num = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
    let buttons:[UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]
    while  !isStringContainedInButtons(buttons) {

        buttons[num].isHidden = !buttons[num].isHidden
    }

}

func isStringContainedInButtons(buttons: [UIButton]) -> Bool {

    for (button in buttons) {
        if (button.titleLabel?.text == cevapLabel.text) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: i wrote code you like said and in if statement i got that error: " Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UILabel?' and 'String?' "
it fixed when im wrote this: if button.titleLabel?.text == cevapLabel.text

but its not hiding buttons randomize when im clicking the eliminateChoicClicked button

Comment: Since I solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand the need for the while loop, I would replace it with

```
if buttons.map($0.title).filter($0 == cevapLabel.text).count == 0 {
  buttons[num].isHidden = !buttons[num].isHidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
for button in buttons {
    if button.title(for: .normal) == cevapLevel.text {
    //your code
   }
}
```